# C++ Noob having issues getting grand totals for entries

Tags: c++

```
int main(void)
{

    StartUp();   //indicates beginning of code

    double startmileage{ 0 };              //indicates starting mileage, initialized at the value of 0
    double endmileage{ 0 };                //indicates ending mileage, initialized at the value of 0
    double milesdriven{ 0 };               //indicates total miles driven, initialized at the value of 0
    double gallonsused{ 0 };               //indicates total gallons used, initialized at the value of 0
    double milespergallon{ 0 };            //indicates total miles per gallon, initialized at the value of 0
    double totalgallonsused{ 0 };
    double totalmilesdriven{ 0 };


    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter the gallons used (-1 to end):  ";                    //prompts user to enter total number of gallons used for trip
        cin >> gallonsused;                                                 //user enters data
        totalgallonsused += gallonsused;
        if (gallonsused == -1) 

        { 
            break;                                                          // Check for sentinel value of -1
        }

        cout << "Enter starting mileage:  ";                                //prompts user to enter start mileage for trip
        cin >> startmileage;                                                //user enters data

        cout << "Enter ending mileage:  ";                                  //prompts user to enter end mileage for trip
        cin >> endmileage;                                                  //user enters data

        milesdriven = endmileage - startmileage;                            //calculates total miles driven
        totalmilesdriven += milesdriven;

        cout << "Miles driven:  " << milesdriven << endl;                   //outputs total miles driven to screen

        milespergallon = milesdriven / gallonsused;                         //calculates total miles per gallon

        cout << "The miles / gallon for this tank was:  " << milespergallon << endl;            //outputs miles per gallon to screen

        cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    }

    // Show grand totals
    cout << "\n\nGrand totals: " << endl;

    cout << "Total gallons used:  " << totalgallonsused << endl;
    cout << "Total miles driven: " << totalmilesdriven << endl;
    cout << "The overall average verage miles/gallon: " << milespergallon <<endl;

    cout << "\n\n" << endl;



WrapUp();
```

Here is what outputs:

```
Enter the gallons used (-1 to end):  12.8
Enter starting mileage:  0
Enter ending mileage:  287
Miles driven:  287
The miles / gallon for this tank was:  22.4219



Enter the gallons used (-1 to end):  10.3
Enter starting mileage:  287
Enter ending mileage:  487
Miles driven:  200
The miles / gallon for this tank was:  19.4175



Enter the gallons used (-1 to end):  5
Enter starting mileage:  487
Enter ending mileage:  607
Miles driven:  120
The miles / gallon for this tank was:  24



Enter the gallons used (-1 to end):  -1


Grand totals:
Total gallons used:  27.1
Total miles driven: 607
The overall average verage miles/gallon: 24



Program Program2.cpp ended successfully.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing `milesdriven` every time around the loop.  Instead, you should accumulate it:

```
milesdriven += endmileage - startmileage;
```

You don't need to calculate miles per gallon until after the loop.  But you do need to calculate `totalgallonsused`:

```
totalgallonsused += gallonsused;
```

And then after the loop:

```
milespergallon = milesdriven / totalgallonsused;
```

Comment: Thank you, Paddy! The requirements are asking for the average after each input, which is why I had it in there before the grand totals. So I made the changes that you recommended, and it's giving grand totals now, though I think the average MPG is still going by the last entry. Here are my modifications:

Comment: Had to modify my initial question to get the code in there. Please see above for modifications

Comment: sorry, was having issues editing. Updated code is present now.

Comment: Okay sure, but that doesn't really change the main thrust of what I'm saying.

Comment: I apologize if I'm misunderstanding something, Paddy. I remodified as you'd stated and now it's giving me a proper average. However, I'm trying to get an exact decimal value without it being rounded. Also, my input for gallons used is coming up to 27.1 for grand total when it should be 28.1, given the entries were 12.8, 10.3, and 5.